# How do I build the source code for controls from Windows Phone toolkit to use with my Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, wptoolkit

The source code for different toolkit controls are available from:
http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

How do I build the same to use it with my Windows Phone 8.1 app (runtime) ?

Comment: Why don't you use the precompiled packages or even the Nuget Package?

Comment: The Nuget packages support only Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight projects and not Windows Phone 8.1 RT.

Comment: Ah yes thats true, I forgott about the API change. I guess you'd have to wait then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone Toolkit for WP8.0 and WP7.0 was build for Silverlight and it has slightly different Controls/Namespaces (more) comparing to Window Runtime.

So in case you want to rebuild Controls for windows runtime, it won't be so simple - you will have to do it manually for the whole code.

For more information about developing for Silverlight and Runtime take a loook [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn632732.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could go for other controls like [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) or [Syncfusion](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) while you wait for WP Toolkit for 8.1 OS. Telerik has really cool controls.